# Which CPU has better IPC using the same TPD, a performance core clocked down or high a efficiency core

Tags: arm, architecture

I'm wondering why the M1 has 4 performance cores and 4 efficiency cores, instead of 8 performance cores with 4 cores running higher efficiency, having the ability to step up to performance.

I understand there is a size difference between efficiency vs performance, but which would perform those efficiency threads better, performance clocked down or straight efficiency

Answer (score 1):

A big core with lots of unused units will consume more power than a streamlined core that has less execution units.

Modern CPU cores can execute multiple different instructions at the same time, the below image is of an Intel Skylake CPU but the general theory is the same. There are multiple EUs (Execution Units) that are capable of executing instructions side by side. In a "simpler" core there will be less control logic overhead, less EUs, and less power consumed on a clock-for-clock basis. Other areas of the "efficiency" cores may well be less complex or have less of the duplicated areas used to achieve the same job simultaneously.

The cores will perform worse, sure, but when your goal is power efficiency rather than performance less is more as they say. The same instruction stream might take longer but it will be with less overhead and waste. If the pipe is *always* full then you achieve more than a half used wider pipe for unit of power.

This is the whole reason for modern hetrogenous cores. Big, wide cores handle heavy lifting, while small efficient cores can do the job when power is scarce. If you don't mind something taking longer then you can save power.

Higher clock speeds also generally mean more power leakage, hence a smaller and lower clocked core can save a bit more power that way as well.

The bigger more complex core will almost always have a higher IPC, but it will be at the cost of higher complexity, more redundant components (when only partially used) and more power waste.

I've written more about modern CPUs at [Can one core perform several operations/instructions during one tick (because core has different execution units)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1478756/can-one-core-perform-several-operations-instructions-during-one-tick-because-co/1478760#1478760)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detail Mokubai, I'm not sure I was able to follow entirely. I understand there's more complexity in the performance core, what I mean to ask, if we clock down the performance core to use the same energy as the efficiency core, which will yield better performance at the same energy consumption

Comment: As I stated "The bigger more complex core will almost always have a higher IPC, but it will be at the cost of higher complexity, more redundant components (when only partially used) and more power waste." So no, if you clock them down the same it will still yield better performance but worse power consumption.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it, it seems the board won't let me upvote your answer, but it certainly deserves it from me